# Difference between loading data (initially empty) and no items

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a page where items are retrieved from an API and then shown on the page.
This API request is done in the `created` hook. I want to show a *[loading]* message when it is still waiting for a response from the API and a *[no items]* message when loading is finished, but there are no items.

Currently I have a `IsEmpty` computed property:

```
isEmpty() {
  return this.cards.length == 0;
}
```

But this is triggered for both situations. How can I create a property to handle both situations?

Comment: By having separate `loading` or an `isBusy` property! What is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a data object property called `loading` which initially set to `true` and reset it to `false` API callback :

```
data(){
  return {
     loading:true
    }
 },
computed:{
   isEmpty() {
       return this.cards.length == 0 || this.loading;
  }
},
created (){
   axios.get(...).then(res=>{
      ...
     this.loading=false;
    })
```